# difference between yarn registry and npm registry

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

Yarn install generates a yarn.lock file which fetches packages from [npmjs](https://registry.npmjs.org).

1. How is [npmjs](https://registry.npmjs.org) different from [yarnpkg](https://registry.yarnpkg.com)?
2. How do I configure yarn to fetch from [yarnpkg](https://registry.yarnpkg.com)?
3. Between [npmjs](https://registry.npmjs.org) and [yarnpkg](https://registry.yarnpkg.com) which one is preferred?

Comment: I think it points to the same npm registry from what I have read.

Comment: so if yarn fetches from npmjs, what fetches from yarnpkg?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As far as the registries go, there is essentially no difference.  According to [one of the Yarn devs](https://twitter.com/madbyk/status/988795518267678720?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E988795520805203969&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.risingstack.com%2Fyarn-vs-npm-node-js-package-managers%2F), they just maintain a server that redirects to NPM's registry so that they can monitor traffic and attempt to speed things up.  And if you want to change a registry, you can do so on a per-project basis by editing the `"registry"` key in your `.npmrc` or globally with `npm config set registry` to use whatever endpoint you want to download from. For yarn you can use `yarn config set registry <registry-url>` with an optional [global flag](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/config/).

Comment: May be this answer should also talk about another choice for setting registry - adding registry config in .yarnrc file